# Get data between current date to last month date from SQLite database

Tags: android, date, android-sqlite

I need to get data in between current date to last month (means last 30 days) from SQlite. 
Here is code to get list of all data but i get nothing from this.

```
public List<Birthday> getWeekBirthdays() {

    List<Birthday> birthdays = new ArrayList<Birthday>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Calendar theEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar theStart = (Calendar) theEnd.clone();
    theStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -30);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String start = dateFormat.format(theStart.getTime());
    String end = dateFormat.format(theEnd.getTime());

    String dateQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_Birthday + " WHERE "
            + KEY_Event_Date + " BETWEEN " + start + " AND " + end;
    Log.e(LOG, dateQuery);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(dateQuery, null);
    Log.e(LOG, "no of birthday : " + c.getCount());
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Birthday birthday = new Birthday();
            birthday.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_User_Name)));
            birthday.setEventType(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_Event_Type)));
            birthday.setEventDate(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_Event_Date)));
            birthday.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            birthdays.add(birthday);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return birthdays;
}
```

I do not get error please help me and tell me how to get these data.

Thanks

Comment: what is type of KEY_Event_Date  ?

Comment: KEY_Event_Date + " TEXT"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is

```
String query="SELECT * from "+TABLE_Birthday +" WHERE "+ KEY_Event_Date +" >= date('now','localtime', '-30 day')"; 

Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(query,null);
```

It will fetch last `30 days` records from today. but your `KEY_Event_Date` must have values in `yyyy-MM-dd` then only it works.

Comment: My Key_Event_Date is Text type when table is created. How i create Key_Event_Date.

Comment: @Shane Don't worry about it. But it's contains value in `yyyy-MM-dd` `(2015-05-08)`

Comment: yes, when i inserted values in database then Key_event_date field having value like - yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: It not giving data of last 30 days. It gives all data which is in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition in your SQL query
**date('now','-29 day')**
This query gives you a date range of 30 days